# Search in a folder with Aptana 3

Tags: eclipse, search, aptana, aptana3

My question sounds quite simple, but I can't find the answer. I just want to be able to search in a specific directory in Aptana, but I can't find the option. CTRL + H gives me the options to search in the Workspace, Selected resources, Enclosing projects or Working set, but not in a directory.

In Atom or Netbeans, you can right-click on a folder and do a search :

[image]

Is it simply not possible with Aptana/Eclipse?

Thank you guys.

Comment: While not as explicit, you could select the directory first and then Ctrl+H using the Selected resources.

Comment: Wow, thank you @nitind, I didn't think about that. Just what I wanted, thank you!